# Spark broadcast big list fail to serialize

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a big list of string (140866 elements) which takes some times to compute. Once computed I want to use this list in UDF or in map of my DataFrame. I follow some tutorials and I found this example

```scala
  val states = List("NY","New York","CA","California","FL","Florida")
  val countries = Map(("USA","United States of America"),("IN","India"))

  val broadcastStates = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(states)
  val broadcastCountries = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(countries)

  val data = Seq(("James","Smith","USA","CA"),
    ("Michael","Rose","USA","NY"),
    ("Robert","Williams","USA","CA"),
    ("Maria","Jones","USA","FL")
  )

  val columns = Seq("firstname","lastname","country","state")
  import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
  val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)

  val df2 = df.map(row=>{
    val country = row.getString(2)
    val state = row.getString(3)

    val fullCountry = broadcastCountries.value.get(country).get
    val fullState = broadcastStates.value(0)
    (row.getString(0),row.getString(1),fullCountry,fullState)
  }).toDF(columns:_*)

  df2.show(false)
```

which works fine.

But when I try to use my list I got this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:283)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:375)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:753)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:730)
  ... 54 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@6ebc6ccc)
```

I get my list with

```scala
val myList = spark.read.option("header",true)
            .csv(NER_PATH_S3)
            .na.drop()
            .filter(col("label") =!= "VALUE" )
            .groupBy("keyword")
            .agg(sum("n_occurences").alias("n_occurences"))
            .filter(col("n_occurences") > 2)
            .filter($"keyword".rlike("[^0-9]+"))
            .select("keyword")
            .collect()
            .map(x => x(0).toString)
            .toList

val myListBroadcast = sc.broadcast(myList)
```

Which I made sure I have exactly the same type as my example, I also try to reduce the size of my list by slicing it.

Comment: can you post complete code ```value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@6ebc6ccc)``` where you are using ```value``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me instead of using

```
sc.broadcast(myList)
```

you can use

```
spark.sparkContext.broadcast(myList)
```

and that should work.

I had faced the similar issue and when I changed the code to what I have suggested it works like a charm.
Happy Learning.